# How to replace the deprecated constructor DynamoDBMapperFieldModel

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Lately, I have to maintain an old project developed in Java (which is not one of my strength) and I've got a warning during the compilation concerning a deprecated API.

After investigation, I found that the deprecated API was the constructor `DynamoDBMapperFieldModel` from AWS.
After looking at the documentation I didn't find any information concerning a new constructor or how to instantiate it through another way.
I need to have this constructor because my class is implementing `ItemConverter` and the method `getFieldModel`

Below you'll find the piece of code of my class:

```java
    @Override
    public DynamoDBMapperFieldModel getFieldModel(Method getter) {

        MethodInfo fieldMeta = meta.get(getter.getDeclaringClass()).get(getter);
        return new DynamoDBMapperFieldModel(getter.toString(), fieldMeta.dynamoDBAttributeType, fieldMeta.marshaller);
    }
```

The version of the SDKs are as follows:
`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.9`
`com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.15`

Let me know if you have any questions and thank you for your help.

Comment: This was annoying to find and [the JavaDocs provides no insight](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/5b688f038b0ec5efd23df3fa2e48700af56361d3/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java#L57).

Comment: I saw that yes, thank you. However that's the deprecated version and I still don't know how to replace it. Do you have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: My answer is based on the inspection of `DynamoDBMapperFieldModel` source code from the release 1.11.15 [found here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/5b688f038b0ec5efd23df3fa2e48700af56361d3/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java). I never have used this API, so take my answer more like an insight provided due the absence of any other answer.

In addition to the aforementioned `deprecated` constructor, the class `DynamoDBMapperFieldModel` provides the following one:

```
/**
 * Creates a new field model instance.
 * @param builder The builder.
 */
private DynamoDBMapperFieldModel(final Builder<T,V> builder) {
    this.id = builder.id;
    this.properties = builder.properties;
    this.reflect = builder.reflect;
    this.converter = builder.converter;
    this.dynamoDBAttributeType = builder.dynamoDBAttributeType;
}
```

However, this constructor is `private`, what means that you cannot call it directly from outside the class scope. It seems that the solution is to use the `DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.Builder` static inner class to instantiate your DynamoDBMapperFieldModel objects. The [class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.ConversionSchemas](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/7bf0fbec42de8a7d54875510f27fb363ca2d19f5/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/ConversionSchemas.java) has some illustrative examples of this idiom, for instance:

```
@Override
public DynamoDBMapperFieldModel getFieldModel(Method getter) {
    //...
    final StandardAnnotationMaps.FieldMap annotations = StandardAnnotationMaps.of(getter, null);
    final DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.Builder builder = new DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.Builder(void.class, annotations);
    builder.with(attributeType);
    return builder.build();
}
```

This idiom is pretty common, very often called as [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

It is noteworthy that the DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.Builder inner class has "default visibility" (no explicit access modifier):

```
static final class Builder<T,V> {
    //...
}
```

You may check [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to be aware about the restrictions of each visibility modifier if necessary.

Hope this help you to find your final solution.